# The difference between python2.7 and python3.6 open audio file ？

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.6

python 2.7

```
fr = open(r'test_audio/16k.wav', 'rb')
audio_data27 = fr.read()
```

python 3.6

```
fr = open(r'test_audio/16k.wav', 'rb')
audio_data36 = fr.read()
```

`audio_data27` type is `str`,but the `audio_data36` type is `bytes`. I want to make the type of `audio_data36` also `str`, what should I do? Thanks!

Comment: Audio _should be bytes_

Comment: in python 2 `str` is a binary type, in python 3 `str` is a text type -- you can roughly think of this as py2 `str` ~= py3 `bytes` and py2 `unicode` ~= py3 `str`

Answer (score -1):

[bytes objects](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0358/) have a `decode()` function that returns a `str` object

Comment: this is not correct, they are asking what **python 2** str and **python3** bytes -- which both represent roughly the same: a binary type

Comment: Doesn't really matter since I was answering the question - _want to make the type of `audio_data36` also `str`_

Comment: Yes,I want to make the `audio_data36` to `str`.

Comment: `decode()` does not work for me. It causes `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 4: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: @shaojie Like I said, audio should be bytes. It is not plain-text that is in UTF-8 (or any other textual unicode) format

Comment: Yes, you are right. Since I want to read the audio file and call the ASR API, but this API is written in Python2.7, I want to switch to Python3.6. In Python2.7, the type of `audio_data` is `str`, and ASR API can be called normally. But in Python 3.6, the type of `audio_data` is `bytes`, and the ASR API cannot be called. So I want to convert `audio_data` to `str` in python3.6 so that ASR API can be called.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what "ASR API" means, and those details weren't really part of the initial question being asked. What exactly is the error you get when sending the bytes object to that API?